# SQL - Get result for sysdate/current Year With Lookback

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic

I have a table with a `NUMBER(4)` column for `MEETINGYEAR`.
Other columns are `MEMBERNO` and `ATTENDEES`.

I want to write a query that looks for a `MEETINGYEAR` that is greater than or equal to "current year" minus 3 years, so that I don't have to manually key in the current year value (ie:2023) each year that I run the query.

Essentially I am looking for where records exist for the current year (2023) OR in the prior 3 years. If found, then result = Y, otherwise N.

This is the best I have done on my own so far:

```
select '4. Annual Meeting Management' Item, 
    decode(count(*),NULL,'N',0,'N','Y') Result 
from member_annual_meeting 
where meetingyear >= '2023'-3;
```

Answer (score 0):

`SYSDATE` is an Oracle function that returns the current date and time (to the nearest second) as a DATE datatype.

You can then use either the `to_char()` or the `extract` functions to extract the year, e.g.:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE), to_char(SYSDATE, 'yyyy') FROM dual;

EXTRACT(YEARFROMSYSDATE) TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY')
------------------------ -----------------------
                    2023 2023
```

Note that `to_char()` returns a character string, so you should really throw a `to_number()` around the whole thing to explicitly convert it into a number. `Extract` returns a number, so that's the one I would recommend you use; no need for additional datatype conversions.